# shortest query to return the list of all users >= 10 Shortest = "least number of characters"

Tags: mysql, sql

Say we have a simple database with two tables:
(1) Users: with one field, user_id
(2) Orders: with two fields: order_id and user_id.

What's the shortest query to return the list of all users with 10 or more orders? Notes:
(a) Shortest = "least number of characters".
(b) Please confirm if you're using MySQL or PostgreSQL syntax.

*Solution*
1)
a)

```
SELECT user_id FROM Users    
JOIN Orders  
ON User.user_id = Orders.user_id
where orders >= 10;
```

b) MySQL

is the above correct?
and is there a shorter way?

**OR**

is the below correct?
and is there a shorter way?
2)
a)

```
SELECT Users.user_id FROM Users 
JOIN Orders  
on Users.user_id = Orders.user_id
group by Orders.user_id
HAVING count(order_id) >= 10;
```

b) MySQL

Comment: Why are you searching the **shortest** query? Database queries should return the expected rows, and you should be able to read and understand them easily. Better use a longer query that is clearly readable

Comment: the first one is not correct. orders < 10 does not make sense

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ - `select user_id from orders group by 1 having count(*)>9`.

Comment: Yes - shortness is an odd request.

Answer (score 0):

Your first query is not correct.  I'm not going to go for shortest, but a decent query would look like:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM Orders 
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10;
```

Whatever query you come up with should be functionally equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

first create a view called maybe V with a working query.
then

```
SELECT * FROM v;
```

Comment: i think that's as short as it gets :)